# Warning: DocumentRoot x does not exist when starting apache2

Tags: apache2

I cloned a rackspace server which had some extra `/var/www/` directories in it that I didn't want. I just wanted to delete websites that I don't need on this server. I thought that was as simple as removing the directories and all files inside each directory.

So I removed them all via command-line. I had to reboot the server. During the reboot, apache failed to start because:

```
DocumentRoot [/var/www/PATH/TO/DIRECTORY/] does not exist
```

In addition, I've got a `[warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts` notice.

My server is running Ubuntu 11.10.

I just wanted to delete directories I wasn't using anymore. How do I clear this up?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The recommended way to enable and disable Apache websites is using the `a2ensite` and `a2dissite` (short for *Apache 2 Enable/Disable Site*).

What these two tools do is basically adding/removing links to/from `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`. Such links point to `/etc/apache2/sites-available`.

Because you have removed the files, I'd recommend not just disabling the sites (i.e. removing the links from `sites-enabled`), but also remove the site configurations all toghether (i.e. removing both the links from `sites-enabled` and the files from `sites-available`).

In short, you should:

1. Find the sites of which you have removed the files: `ls /etc/apache2/sites-enabled`
2. Disable such sites: `rm /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/site1 /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/site2`
3. (Optional) totally remove the configuration files for such sites: `rm /etc/apache2/sites-available/site1 /etc/apache2/sites-available/site2`

Comment: Yes this is what I did, however manually because I learned this the hard way. Thank you for your thorough answer. I'm sure I'll refer to this again in the future for clarification.

Comment: i did ls /etc/apache2/sites-available and there was a conf file there which was removed previously.. just removed that file and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell with what little configuration information you posted.

You need to check your Apache configuration files and virtual hosts. If you are no longer using `/var/www/PATH/TO/DIRECTORY/` , disable the virtual host that is using that directory and/or update your apache configuration.

See:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP

https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/httpd.html

If that does not solve the problem, please update your question and provide additional configuration information.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but I don't know anything about VirtualHosts. I just wanted to delete websites that I don't need on this server. I thought that was as simple as removing the directories and all files inside each directory. I updated my question a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to remove VirtualHosts pertaining to the files I deleted inside `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`.